# Setting bootloader password in EL7

Tags: centos7, rhel7, grub2, boot-loader

Using [this guide](https://highon.coffee/blog/security-harden-centos-7/#set-boot-loader-password) I am attempting to add a bootloader password to a CentOS7 install.

> When prompted, enter the password that was selected and insert the
>   returned password hash into the appropriate grub2 configuration
>   file(s) under /etc/grub.d immediately after the superuser account.
>   (Use the output from grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 as the value of
>   password-hash):

I've created the "superusers-accountpassword-hash" using `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`, but am not seeing where to add this line:

```
password_pbkdf2 superusers-accountpassword-hash
```

The only files in /etc/grub.d/ are binaries.   The guide says not to use /etc/grub.cfg since this is overwritten by `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Where does the `password_pbkdf2` directive go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create /etc/grub.d/01_users file and place the info in there. This typically is created when GRUB boot loader password is used in a kickstart template but must be made manually otherwise.

Source:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_Password_Protection.html